# aiohttp not using system proxy settings configured by zscalar

Tags: python-3.x, api, aiohttp, zscaler

I have a desktop application written in python which uses aiohttp package to make api calls. So the problem I am facing is the api calls works perfectly when there is no proxy settings but when we install our app on a system which use proxy settings the api fails.

> Cannot connect to host api.abc.com:443 ssl:default [getaddrinfo
> failed]

I have read many articles but none define how to use system proxy settings. Few recommend to use trust_env but it does not work

```
async with aiohttp.ClientSession(trust_env=True) as session:
    async with session.post(url, json=body, headers=headers) as response:
        data = await response.read()
        data = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))
        return response.status, data
```

Environment:

```
System settings are set by Zscalar
Python 3.8
aiohttp 3.8.1
Windows 10 pro 64 bit
```

Comment: Have you tried `session.post(url, json=body, headers=headers, proxy=YOUR_PROXY_URL)` ?

Comment: I dont have proxy url and it will be not possible to ask since client is insisting on using system configured proxy setting. Is there any other package I can try ??

Comment: You can get proxy variable from environment using for example `os.environ["NAME_OF_PROXY_ENV_VARIABLE"]`